# Customizing select box with css behaves differently in different browsers?

Tags: css, select

I have customized HTML select box to look like this

[image]

But it is appearing differently in different browsers. In Mozilla it is working fine. But in IE and Chrome it is not displaying as it is displaying in Mozilla.

Even the options border is not displaying properly.

Please help me.

here is the 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKH6L/)

Comment: why it is down voted. please tell me if you are not understanding, i will give you some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Many things render differently in different browsers. Although things are getting better, cross-browser testing still takes a large percentage of any web developers role.

Form elements are especially difficult to style effectively because their visual appearance is controlled by the underlying OS as well as the browser.

To style select boxes consistently across  browsers, you will need to use something like [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) (requires jQuery)

Comment: Use Uniform to handle replacing the select box, then override the styles that it adds using your own CSS